# JQuery UI Datepicker parseDate 'Missing number at position 6'

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-parsing

I need to parse dates like '070126' to '26 Jan 2007'. I thought I could use the datepicker, but it gives me the an error...

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('ymmdd', '070126') #=> Missing number at position 6
```

I am starting to think that this could be a bug...

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('y-mm-dd', '07-01-26') #=> Fri Jan 26 2007 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Any advice?

Thanks..

Comment: Ensure you have the latest version, as this was a bug that was fixed - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/a2e0eb920aaa41e6248e1a2f7d013997ba4f421f

Comment: simple whitespace error, `dateString = dateString.trim();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i just preprocessed the date.
The function add_scores() just adds '-' after each two characters.

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('ymmdd', add_scores('070126'));


add_scores('070126'); //=> '07-01-26'

function normalize_date(date){
        var normalized_date = [];
        $.each("ymd", function(index, format_option){
            normalized_date.push(date[index*2] + date[(index*2)+1]);
        });
        return normalized_date.toString().replace(/,/g, '-');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not working? I have no problems with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ND2Qg/

Comment: JQuery 1.4.4+ no problem. but i'm using JQuery 1.4.2 (http://jsfiddle.net/ND2Qg/3/)... Damn. +1 for jsfiddle.net, just love it! Thanks!