# parsedate function not working

Tags: jquery

The parsedate function is not working in the following: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L1zfsnxc/)

I am using jquery 1.10.2

What is wrong with the following?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        $('#date1').text($.datepicker.parseDate('ymmdd', date));
    });
</script> 
<html>
    <body>
        First date: <span id="date1"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First include **jQuery UI** library to your fiddle and see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390521/jquery-ui-datepicker-parsedate-missing-number-at-position-6) may help you!

Comment: @Dhaval it does not help

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/L1zfsnxc/3/

use this rather

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

$('#date1').html(today);

});
```

Comment: I am having the error throw "Missing number at position " + iValue;

Comment: thank you , what I need to do is to compare dates... I can`t use this to compare 100 dates.. Why is dateparse not working

Comment: you cant use parseDate like this rather you can use parseDate like $.datepicker.parseDate('yyMMdd', '2014september06');